# how do i change the domain of a action from a field in odoo

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-15

There is a default many2one field in `'hr.employee'` model called `'parent_id'`(Manager)
My requirement is:

If there is any record on that `parent_id` field then the action of `'calendar.event'` domain will be `[('user_id','=',user.id)]` if no record is present then domain will be `[(1,'=',1)]`

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks

Comment: sorry, i have misunderstood your needs

Comment: yeah i tried that too what you suggesed still I didn't get the result

Answer (score 0):

If you want a `calendar.event` action to be updated based on an `hr.employee` record, then you will need to connect the two models. What is your plan on connecting them? Will the `calendar.event` have the `[('user_id', '=', user.id)]` domain if `user.employee_id.parent_id`? Are you trying to pull up a tree view of `calendar.event` for all the records associated with the `hr.employee` record that the user is looking at?

If this is the case, then one possible solution is to add a button to the form view of the employee. You will need to replace `<view_id>` with the view you want it to redirect to. Here is the code for the Python:

```py
from odoo import _, api, fields, models


class HrEmployee(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'hr.employee'
  
    def action_list_events(self):
        self.ensure_one()
        if not self.parent_id:
            domain = [('1', '=', '1')]
        elif self.user_id:
            domain = [('user_id', '=', self.user_id.id)]
        else:
            return
        return {
            'name': _("Create Event"),
            'res_model': 'calendar.event',
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'view_id': self.env.ref('<view_id>').id,
            'view_mode': 'tree',
            'domain': domain,
        }
```

And the button:

```xml
<button name="action_list_events"/>
```

**Edit**: Since you're wanting to limit the all calendar events based on the current user, try this instead:

```py
from odoo import api, fields, models


class CalendarEvent(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'calendar.event'

    allowed_user_ids = fields.Many2many('res.users', compute='_compute_allowed_user_ids', store=True, string="Allowed Users")

    @api.depends('user_id')
    def _compute_allowed_user_ids(self):
        for record in self:
            employee_id = self.env.user.employee_id
            if employee_id and employee_id.parent_id:
                domain = [('user_id', '=', self.env.user.id)]
            elif employee_id and not employee_id.parent_id:
                domain = []
            else:
                record.allowed_user_ids = False
                continue
            record.allowed_user_ids = self.env['res.users'].search(domain)
```

And you can either use a record rule or apply it to a specific action window:

```xml
<record id="calendar_event_allowed_user_ir_rule" model="ir.rule">
    <field name="name">Allowed Users</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_calendar_event"/>
    <field name="domain_force">[('allowed_user_ids', 'in', [user.id])]</field>
    <field name="groups" eval="[(4, ref('base.group_user'))]"/>
</record>
```

```xml
<record id="calendar_event_allowed_user_window" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Calendar Events</field>
    <field name="res_model">calendar.event</field>
    <field name="view_mode">calendar,tree,form</field>
    <field name="domain">[('allowed_user_ids', 'in', [user.id])]</field>
</record>
```

Comment: no i am not trying to pull that up, I am trying that, if the user logged in currently, for that user in hr.employee has any record in parent_id field then I want a domain in calendar.event "[('user_id', '=', self.user_id.id)]" and if there is no record in parent_id field the domain will be [('1', '=', '1')] on the action.,Thats all

Comment: @SidharthPanda See the edit I added.